# Does anyone know how to use plotly express offline?

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter

I am trying to run an example code to visualise a plotly chart, as below:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot, plot
import plotly.offline as py  
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Europe', 586098529, 'Total'], ['Asia', 3811953827, 'Total'],
    ['France', 61083916, 'Europe'], ['Germany', 82400996, 'Europe'], ['Italy', 58147733, 'Europe'],
    ['Spain', 40448191, 'Europe'], ['United Kingdom', 60776238, 'Europe'], ['Taiwan', 23174294, 'Asia'],
    ['Japan', 127467972, 'Asia'], ['Korean', 49044790, 'Asia'], ['China', 1318683096, 'Asia']],
    columns=['country', 'pop', 'continent'])
fig = px.sunburst(df, names='country', values='pop', parents='continent', title='Population')

plot(fig,show_link = False)
```

When I run this, a new internet browser opens up to show the chart. Is there a way to show this just in Jupyter itself?

Comment: Try this: `fig.show()` instead of `plot(fig,show_link = False)`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately nothing appears in my notebook when I do that. Just a blank output.

Comment: Try fig.show("notebook")

Answer (score 0):

1. as @r-beginners mentioned, fig.show() displays a graph in Jupyter
2. check if you've installed `ipywidgets>=7.5` for Jupyter Notebook or `jupyterlab-plotly` and `plotlywidget` for Jupyter Lab
3. check out [this StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412012/jupyter-notebook-plotly-not-showing-graph-just-graph)
4. [getting started guide by plotly](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/)
5. [troubleshooting guide](https://plotly.com/python/troubleshooting/#jupyter-classic-notebook-problems)